# how do i optimize my BTRFS System for high throughput

Tags: linux, btrfs

I am unable to effective run a high performance program on my linux system due to performance issues. I want to know if there are specific optimization techniques that i can enable to improve
I/O read and writes and the overall disk throughput.

I have also noticed that BTRF filesystem are slower compared to EXT4 filesystem so this might be a factor.

I read the documentation on the software, it seems to implement heavy write usage, using 5GB of /tmp files, and storing up to 50 GB of dumped log files.

Comment: The use case of I/O is also important. What is a "high performance program"?

Comment: yeah, pretty certainly Linux was sensibly configured to achieve best performance in some "average" use case scenario. You seem to have a different one. Without knowing *what* to optimize for, you cannot optimize. What's your access pattern? Read? Write? Mixed? What is the structure of the underlying storage? What kind of safety do you need?

Comment: also, if your in need of a high perf file system, why btrfs? https://openbenchmarking.org/result/2108260-PTS-SSDS978300

Comment: You'll get much better answers if you can make this more concrete. If you can't share the specific program and performance issues you're running into, consider trying to reproduce them with available tools/benchmarks, and show the output of tools like iostat. If not that: try to share the specs of a different system that you know can/does run the program effectively.

Comment: What kind of write usage? If it's "50GB of dumped log files", are those written in an append-only manner? Are those plain text logs? If so, they might be compressible in which case compress=zstd:1 could help a ton.

Comment: It is append mode, as it reads it from it's buffer. Yeah plain text log file

Comment: Thanks, I will try mounting my btrfs partition with the flag (compress=zstd).